# Returning an index value from a List View Control

Tags: vb.net

I have a list view control that users can add items to but I need to be able to tell what item they have selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SelectedIndices` property. The `SelectedItems` property will return you the actual objects that are in the list (which you may have to do anyways).

EDIT: Sample (sorry, my VB may be rusty):

```
If myListView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0 Then
    int selectedIndex = myListView.SelectedIndices[0];
    ' Do other stuff
End If
```

Comment: It returns the same error and there still is no way to parse the value

Comment: It's a collection of values, because the user could possibly select multiple items. If your ListView is in single-selection mode, use SelectedIndices[0]. But make sure to test SelectedIndices.Count to see if anything is selected.

Comment: I am getting an error that says its an Invalid Argument. It is saying that the value of 0 is not valid for 'index'

Comment: See my previous comment about testing SelectedIndices.Count -- if there is no selection, this collection is empty, and trying to get the value at index 0 will result in an error. I will put an example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, intcurrent value in the wrong block in the count check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedItems property returns a list of which of the list view items have been selected.  If you only want them to be able to select a single item you can set the MultiSelect property to false.

Comment: I come up with an error that says it cannot convert it into an integer, and I can't find a way to parse the value.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  The SelectedItems property returns a collection of ListViewItem objects.  If you want the index of the item as an integer look at the Index property of the individual ListViewItem.  For example, lst.SelectedItems(0).Index will give you the index of the first selected item.

Comment: Private Sub lbxLog_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbxLog.SelectedIndexChanged

'intCurrent is an Integer
intCurrent = lbxLog.SelectedIndices

End Sub

Comment: Sorry, it just bunched it all up